# Hopf invariant depends only on the homotopy type

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

This is a question about Hopf invariant, discussed in Section 4.B of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. [http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)

Hatcher says that (in p.427 of the book) that the Hopf invariant of $f:S^{2n-1}\to S^n$ ($n>1$) depends only on the homotopy class of $f$, because under the homotopy equivalence $C_f\simeq C_g$ the chosen generators $\beta$ for $H^{2n}(C_f)$ and $H^{2n}(C_g)$ correspond, but I can't see why. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator $\beta$ is defined by the property that it is sent to a fixed generator of $H^{2n}(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n})$ by $H^{2n}(C_f,S^n) \to H^{2n}(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n})$, where the latter is induced by a map $(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n})\to (C_f, S^n)$ which is simply the attaching map.

But if $f\simeq g$, then you can construct a homotopy equivalence $C_f\to C_g$ which is compatible with these attaching maps, that is, such that the following square commutes up to homotopy

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n}) @>>> (C_f,S^n) \\
@VidVV @VVV\\
(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n}) @>>> (C_g,S^n)\end{CD}$$

that's essentially the content of proposition 0.18 (which Hatcher mentions in the paragraph you're referring to), or rather it follows from the proof of that proposition.

Since this square commutes up to homotopy, the corresponding square in cohomology commutes on the nose:

$$\begin{CD}H^{2n}(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n}) @<<< H^{2n}(C_f,S^n) \\
@AidAA @AAA\\
H^{2n}(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n}) @<<< H^{2n}(C_g,S^n)\end{CD}$$

which means that the generator for $C_g$ which is sent to the chosen generator of $H^{2n}(D^{2n},\partial D^{2n})$ is sent to the corresponding one for $C_f$, which is the claim.

Comment: Do you mean that the proof of Proposition 0.18 implies that the two maps $X_1\to X_0\sqcup_f X_1$ and $X_1\to X_0\sqcup_g X_1$ are homotopic? (in the notation of this proposition)

Comment: Written as such it doesn't make sense, as they don't land in the same space they are, however, homotopic if you compose one with a homotopy equivalence of the codomains (essentially because the two canonical inclusions $X_1\to X_1\times I$ are homotopic)